# Would Google Sheets LOOKUP recognize 0-50 as 0 through 50?

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering the possibility of an answer to the  question in my title.

The formula I have is:

```
=LOOKUP(A1, E1:E3, F1:F3)
```

Here,

`A1` can be any value from say 0 to 1000.

`E1:E3` contain different ranges.

```
 E1 = 0-50
 E2 = 51-800
 E3 = 801-1000
```

`F1:F3` contains a description for each of those ranges.

What is the best way to lookup the value and assign a description? Would I have to have a data list with 1000 entries? Or can Google sheets recognize 0-50 as a range of  numbers from 0 to 50?

(I don't want to do an if statement to accomplish this.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you construct your lookup table as shown (the bounds of the ranges, rather than pairs of limits, and in order) you can rely of the lack of the fourth parameter in a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) to select *either* an exact match *or*, when no exact match, the match for the next lower value:

[image: WA110146 example]

Comment: The same would also be done by LOOKUP.